# How can I load a keras model into a Rmarkdown file and predict within the knitr?

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to generate a plot of predictions with a previously trained model using keras tensoflow.

I use a chunk to try to load the model saved with the function:

```
save_model_hdf5()
```

this is saved in a R script separate from the Rmd file.

Once i have the model, I try to load it inside a chunk from the Rmarkdown file so I can use it to produce a plot of predictions:

````
```{r}
model_h <- load_model_hdf5("pogen/investigacions/modelo_keras/modelo_regresion/model_upto_2019.h5")
model_h %>% summary()```
````

When I click knit, the following error appears:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 


OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: pogen/investigacions/modelo_keras/modelo_regresion/model_upto_2019.h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Detailed traceback: 
  File "/home/ariel/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 189, in load_model
    loader_impl.parse_saved_model(filepath)
  File "/home/ariel/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 113, in parse_saved_model
    constants.SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME_PB))
Calls: <Anonymous> ... load_model -> do.call -> <Anonymous> -> py_call_impl
Execution halted
```

I don't know if someone has encountered this error before that could guide me towards finding a solution.

Comment: often the working directory in your R session is not the same one used when a .Rmd is knit. I would try using the absolute file path or explicitly change the working directory within the chunk

Comment: I already declared the path with 'knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = "~/")', and i extract the file using absolute path, but it seems the 'load_model_hdf5' function is using a different method for assigning the hdf5 file to an object inside the Rmd file.